# nginx issue. while starting

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

While starting my nginx

I am getting the following error message

```
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx14-nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-05-16 16:06:15 +08; 11s ago
  Process: 7839 ExecStartPre=/opt/rh/nginx14/root/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
 systemd[1]: nginx14-nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 nginx[7839]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "proxy_ssl_server_name" in /opt/rh/nginx14/root/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:67
 nginx[7839]: nginx: configuration file /opt/rh/nginx14/root/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
 systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
 systemd[1]: Unit nginx14-nginx.service entered failed state.
 systemd[1]: nginx14-nginx.service failed.
```

nginx.conf

```
  59
     60
     61         location /HEAD/ServerInfoService {
     62                 proxy_pass https://-----------------------Service;
     63                 proxy_set_header Host -------------.net;
     64                 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     65                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     66                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     67                 proxy_ssl_server_name on;
     68                 proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     69         }
     70
```

Comment: Please check that your nginx built with the `--with-http_ssl_module` configuration parameter.

Comment: We commented out and checked it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx 1.4 as it seems from your output, problem is that the `proxy_ssl_server_name` directive has been added to nginx on version 1.7.0 as clearly stated in the official documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name